# Css style changing when dialog window is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

[Example of site with dialog window](http://codepen.io/a191919/pen/VaNWQO)

Why after clicking on `Login` and opening Dialog Window. Style of Main page is changing. For example when Dialog window closed .css of body is

```
body {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:70%;
}
```

when it's opened

```
body {
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

How to prevent changing body style when dialog window is opened?

Comment: To assist with this problem, we'll also need to see the html and javascript code that is being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the styling from the body and add it to a div that encapsules everything else.

So change body to look like this...

```
body {
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

and add a div

```
  <body ng-app="MyApp">
    <div style="position:absolute;width:70%;left:15%">
     ...
    </div>
  </body>
```

Here is what it should look like on codepen

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QNPMWO